# Oracle-xe docker container have weird behaviour

Tags: docker, oracle-xe-18.4

I am new to docker I have been trying to install oracel-18xe in the docker
after installing Oracele-xe which seems to be working but
after running **./buildContainerImage.sh** command
I got the following logs.

```
Removing intermediate container 3cd9a901da82
 ---> 3ed5c215ef81
Step 7/8 : HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --start-period=5m    CMD "$ORACLE_BASE/$CHECK_DB_FILE" >/dev/null || exit 1
 ---> Running in a1c6507ac3b9
Removing intermediate container a1c6507ac3b9
 ---> f48555c74740
Step 8/8 : CMD exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE
 ---> Running in c36aec16a658
Removing intermediate container c36aec16a658
 ---> a347238232be
Successfully built a347238232be
Successfully tagged oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

which seems correct, Then I run the command

```
sudo docker run --name myxedb     -d     -p 51521:1521     -p 55500:5500     -e ORACLE_PWD=<secret>     -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8     oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

that runs with out error but after running **docker logs** command
I found the following logs.

```
sed: can't read /etc/oratab: No such file or directory
/opt/oracle/runOracle.sh: line 194: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/oratab: No such file or directory
#####################################
########### E R R O R ###############
DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
Please check output for further info!
########### E R R O R ###############
#####################################
The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
/opt/oracle/checkDBStatus.sh: line 18: oraenv: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open '/opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/*/*/trace/alert*.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

but when I run **docker ps** command I have not found any container running
then after googling I found an other variation the command

```
sudo docker run --name myxedb2   -d  -i  -t  -p 51521:1521     -p 55500:5500     -e ORACLE_PWD=<secret>     -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8     oracle/database:18.4.0-xe /bin/bash
```

after that I was able to see the results in the **docker ps** command.
but **docker logs** command is showing nothing.

I have some questions here.

first of-all why the first **docker run** command was not running and **docker logs** command showing logs which is quite normal.

secondly why the second command is showing all good but **docker logs** are showing nothing.

and 3rdly the **docker images** command shows the following out put at my side

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
oracle/database                  18.4.0-xe   a347238232be   2 days ago     319MB
oraclelinux                      7-slim      0a28ba78f4c9   7 weeks ago    132MB
```

but the forums I am following shows the the size which is quite different from my side.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
oracle/database     18.4.0-xe           926f4349b277        12 minutes ago      5.89GB
oraclelinux         7-slim              153f8d73287e        8 weeks ago         131MB
```

Need suggesting and help needed here, thanks advance.

Regards,

Comment: I was able to run oracle 11 with docker. Does it help you?

Comment: yeah, if the latest client work fine with it.